# Can't use Xamarin Webview after Alert.Cancel();

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

I am using webview element in xamarin android app. I'm alerting problems and I can not use webview after alert.Cancel(); or alert.Dismiss();

Do you have any idea why i can't touch or click in webview after the closing alert dialog?

UPDATE:

```
view = FindViewById<Webview>(Resource.Id.MyView)
view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
view.LoadUrl("www.google.com");
AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).Create();
alert.SetTitle("Uppss");
alert.SetMessage("Something wrong!");
alert.SetCancelable(true);
alert.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
alert.SetButton( "Go Back", (go, bk) =>
 {
     alert.Cancel();
     alert.Dismiss();
 });
alert.Show();
```

Comment: Is there any errors? The `AlertDialog` code is correct, please show your `WebView` code. And your question is very not clear for us, it is appreciated  that you provide a simple which will show your problem.

Comment: Have you use `SetWebViewClient` method on your `view`? I have tried many times, but I can't reproduce your problem.